# Class with list initalization of map with function pointers

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, list-initialization

I'm trying to write a class that will receive a (number of) pair(s) of char arrays (and strings, later down) and function pointers, from which I plan to use the desired function. I'm using a modified version of the code presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884392/constructing-a-stdmap-from-initializer-list-error) for testing purposes, so I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    std::map<const char*, void(*)()> m_ints;
public:
    Test(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char*, void(*)()>> init):
    m_ints(init)
    {}
};

void testfunction(){
    cout << "This is a test function"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test t = { {"hello", &testfunction} };
    return 0;
}
```

Which, when compiled with g++, returns an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map < const char*, void (\*)()>::map(std::initializer_list < std::pair < const char*, void (*)()> >&)’ 

     m_ints(init)
                ^
```

and a *VERY* long list of notes with candidates. What am I doing wrong, can I initialize my map like this, or should I use an initializer function within the class?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but you have a flaw in your map: You use the *pointer* as key, not the string it might point to. If you want to have the string be the key then you need to use `std::string`.

Comment: Another couple of notes: The reason that keys must be constant is because `std::map` is ordered on the key, and the ordering is maintained only on insertion. And if you don't care about ordering, then you should probably use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Finally, for more flexibility, don't use function pointers. Use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead, which can handle bound member functions as well as lambdas, besides normal functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Alright, I'll make the due changes in the real program, I'm very new to C++ so thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @guscomm If you are new to C++ I strongly recommend you follow @Someprogrammerdude advice of storing `std::string` instead of `const char*`. There are so many things that could go wrong when you manipulate char arrays, and most of the issues are solved by using classes such as `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the link you mentioned, you need to `const`-ify the typename of the key in the initializer-list, e.g.:

```
std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char* const, void(*)()>>
```

Notice the key is `const char* const` and not `const char*`.

[Example](https://ideone.com/sYLyM4)

If you don’t want to bother with the painful task of making the type `const`, you can use the `value_type` instead, e.g.:

```
std::initializer_list<decltype(m_ints)::value_type>
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/yFLaRY)

Comment: @guscomm I edited the answer to include the `value_type`-based solution, if you prefer that.